# how can I set a breakpoint in squeak code?

Tags: squeak, gnu-smalltalk

Hey, friends, Squeak is powerful, I knows that the Debugger in squeak played a central role, now I wanner to set a breakpoint in squeak code,  should be `self: halt`, My problem is that
how can I quickly trace into the code-piece where I set an breakpoint?

Comment: What do you mean by *trace into the code-piece*? Note, it should be `self halt`, not `self: halt`

Comment: Exactly self halt. I means if I doubt some piece of code have bugs, and have not designed by contract( no keyword assert in code),then I set some breakpoint in the specific code pieces where may raise error.

Comment: Hi @parsifal. Sorry, I still didn't get you... Is the question answered by my above comment?

Comment: I have answered the questions, thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by myself :)

Assume we  have a suffix method add to String, and it is not a buggy method!

```
1  suffix
2  "assumes that I'm a file name, and answers my suffix, the part after the last dot"
3    | dot dotPosition |
4   dot := FileDirectory dot asCharacter.
5   dotPosition := (self size to: 1 by: -1) detect: [ :i | (self at: i) = dot ].
6   self halt.
7   ^ self copyFrom: dotPosition to: self size
```

notice the line 7 `self halt` added .
we can also just edit the suspect code by inserting self halt.

When we run this method, the execution of the self halt will bring up the
pre-debugger, from where we can proceed, or go into the debugger and
look at variables, step the computation, and edit the code.